# Loading multiple fits files through one line

Tags: python, for-loop, fits

I have 200 fits files that I need to load in and average out to create a map. However, I was wondering if there is a way to do this all in one line rather than 200 "fits.open" lines. I saw it somewhere but I cannot recall where.

The file names go as Coadd000_5.fits, Coadd001_5.fits, Coadd002_5.fits, Coadd003_5.fits ... Coadd199_5.fits.

So it has to be something similar to

```
hdulist2 = fits.open('/Users/alibinesh/Desktop/Data/actpolS2Lensing/actPolS2LensProducts/realKappaCoadd' + xyz + '_5.fit')
```

or something similar to that. Would I have to do a for loop with i going from 0 to 199?

Comment: What's wrong with the for loop? I find it the easiest and cleanest way.

Comment: Yeah, probably use a loop. You can loop over range(200) if you write a function that, for each number i, produces the file name for the ith file, and then another function that does the appropriate processing of the given file name. That's just a high-level suggestion; there's many ways to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be trying to remember the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which is a neat, readable way of doing `for` loops.

```
mylist = [ deal_with( 'realKappaCoadd%03d_5.fit' % i ) for i in range(200) ]
```

(file path shortened for readability)

Any time you find yourself wanting to initialize an empty `list` and then `.append()` to it in a `for` loop, think ["list comprehension"](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to do it in one line.  Or ["generator expression"](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), which is a closely-related syntax but one which evaluates lazily (that would allow you to process thing "depth-first" while superficially *appearing* to go breadth-first, but I doubt there's any real advantage to that in your case).

You might also find it useful to iterate over the output of `glob` which will find all filenames matching a certain pattern:

```
import glob
list_of_filenames = sorted( glob.glob( 'realKappaCoadd*_5.fit' ) )
mylist = [ deal_with( filename ) for filename in list_of_filenames ]
```

Since (from comments) it seems that opening a `fits` file entails a lot of overhead, you probably only want one open at a time.  Therefore you should operate efficiently "depth-first", completely finishing your business with one file before moving on to the next. IMO the most readable way of doing that is to put all the necessary steps for one file, in sequence, in your `deal_with` function:

```
def deal_with(single_filename):
    file_handle = fits.open(single_filename)
    result = do_whatever_processing(file_handle)
    # ...
    # if necessary, explicitly close the file here
    return result
```

Comment: This answer and the other one are both giving bad advice w.r.t. FITS files.  `fits.open(...)` can have a lot of overhead.  Instead the OP should open one file at a time in a loop and compute a running mean of the data in the files.  There is not likely any sense in keeping every file open simultaneously.

Comment: @Iguananaut that might be a good case for a generator expression instead - see edit

Comment: With all due respect, that isn't useful here. All the OP needs to know, it seems, is how to write a for loop. There's no advantage to using a generator expression to loop over some FITS files and do something with them. I'm the (former) maintainer of the astropy.io.fits library.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop:

```
dirname = '<path_to_files>'
average = 0
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(dirname, 'Coadd*_5.fits')):
    with fits.open(filename) as hdul:
        # Update 'average', whatever that means in this specific case
```

Don't open every file simultaneously as in the other answers--this can incur significant overhead and probably is not something you need just to average over some data in each file (or even if you do need simultaneous access to multiple simultaneous files, you should just read the relevant portions into memory and close the files).

What specifically are you trying to do?  Chances are there's already a library that will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily with a for loop:

```
hdulist2 = [fits.open('/Users/alibinesh/Desktop/Data/actpolS2Lensing/actPolS2LensProducts/realKappaCoadd%03d_5.fit' % i) for i in range(200)]
```

Comment: `str(i)` won't get you the files in which the serial number has leading zeros

Comment: Ah true. And I should've used a list comprehension. Thanks

Comment: It's perfectly valid to use a multi-line `for` loop instead of a list comprehension (although I'm pretty sure the OP was trying to remember the latter) depending on which you find more readable.  I just wanted to point out the completely unrelated string-formatting problem (which could occur in either looping approach).

Comment: Yep, I know it's valid, it just looks better with a list comprehension. And your comment about the formatting was also valid, it does need the `"%03d"`